# Find Range With and Without Variable

Tags: excel, vba, find, range

I have an Excel Sheet with a column filled with dates, and a code which needs to find range with a given date in this column/range - `rngsaison1`. Then the code needs to find the range with the same date after the given range - `rngsaison2`.

```
    Set rngsaison1 = .Range("O:O").Find(What:=CDate(.Range("N27")), LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set rngsaison2 = .Range("O:O").Find(What:=firstDate, after:=rngsaison1, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

The variable `firstDate` is the string variable of `CDate(.Range("N27"))`. With this method, both of the ranges (`rngsaison1` and `rngsaison2`) are found in one of my files, however, in the other file the first row in the code runs on Run Time Error 91.
If I change `CDate(.Range("N27"))` to `firstDate` in the first row, it'll find only the second occurance of the date in `.Range("O:O")`.

Do you have any idea, what could be the reasons behind both of these issues? The References of the workbooks/files are the same, the formats in the sheets are the same, I work with the files in the same environment in Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus.

Thank you very much in advance for your replies!

BR,
Péter

Comment: You might have text that looks like dates, instead of true dates.

Comment: It could be what @BigBen comment, or how you are referencing `.Range("N27")` and `FirstDate`? Probably need to see more of your code.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, eventually I've found (kind of) a solution: I changed `firstDate` to `Date` format from `String`, and then with `CStr(firstDate)` it works properly. A bit strange, but does the job..